# What does an A-final case mean in terms of police cases?

Tags: dialogue, talaash

I'm not sure whether this question fits here or not. I was watching the movie 'Talaash: The Answer Lies Within', 2012 movie directed by Reema Kagti.

In the movie, many police officers addressed a case as "A-final case". From what I understood I think they either meant a case which never got solved or a case which involved high profile people.

I looked for the term on google but didn't find anything remotely close to it. I guess it's just an alias or a pseudonym for some another term. Please help me in finding the meaning of this term.

Comment: i assume a final case means the final case attended by one police officer before he retired or died

Comment: No, I don't think this is the case. Because the officer handling the case was not so aged and his case was a 'A-final' case.